# Cannot add foreign key constraint creating tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, minecraft

The method `createTable()` is working, I've been creating other simple tables without issues.

I'm using MySQL server 8.0

This is a test for the tables, then I will make a script to create them. I keep having this error:

> Could not create table, SQLException: Cannot add foreign key constraint

But I dont know what is wrong.

```
    if(!database.checkTable("maps")){
        String maps = "CREATE TABLE maps (" 
                + "name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,"
                + "mapType VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,"
                + "world VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,"
                + "referenceId INT(32) NOT NULL,"
                + "regionId INT(32) NOT NULL,"
                + "testmode BIT(1) NOT NULL,"
                + "edition BIT(1) NOT NULL,"
                + "finished BIT(1) NOT NULL,"
                + "PRIMARY KEY (name, referenceId, regionId))"
                + "ENGINE = InnoDB "
                + "DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;";
        database.createTable(maps);
    }
    if(!database.checkTable("regions")){
        String regions = "CREATE TABLE regions ("
                + "id INT(32) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT," 
                + "minLocationId INT(32) NOT NULL,"
                + "maxLocationId INT(32) NOT NULL,"
                + "PRIMARY KEY (id, minLocationId, maxLocationId),"
                + "CONSTRAINT `regionMapFk`"
                + "FOREIGN KEY (id)"
                + "REFERENCES maps (regionId)"
                + "ON DELETE CASCADE "
                + "ON UPDATE CASCADE)"
                + "ENGINE = InnoDB "
                + "DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;";
        database.createTable(regions);
    }
    if(!database.checkTable("locations")){
        String locations = "CREATE TABLE locations ("   
                + "id INT(16) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "
                + "x INT(16) NOT NULL, "
                + "y INT(16) NOT NULL, "
                + "z INT(16) NOT NULL, "
                + "PRIMARY KEY(id),"
                + "CONSTRAINT `minLocationRegionFk`"
                + "FOREIGN KEY (id)"
                + "REFERENCES regions (minLocationId)"
                + "ON DELETE CASCADE "
                + "ON UPDATE CASCADE,"
                + "CONSTRAINT `maxLocationRegionFk`"
                + "FOREIGN KEY (id)"
                + "REFERENCES regions (maxLocationId)"
                + "ON DELETE CASCADE "
                + "ON UPDATE CASCADE,"
                + "CONSTRAINT `locationMapFk`"
                + "FOREIGN KEY (id)"
                + "REFERENCES maps (referenceId)"
                + "ON DELETE CASCADE "
                + "ON UPDATE CASCADE)"
                + "ENGINE = InnoDB "
                + "DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;";
        database.createTable(locations);
    }
```

> [23:51:36 WARN]: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot add foreign key
>   constraint [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3593) [23:51:36
>   WARN]:        at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3525) [23:51:36
>   WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1986)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2140) [23:51:36
>   WARN]:        at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2620)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2570)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:779) [23:51:36
>   WARN]:        at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:622) [23:51:36
>   WARN]:        at power.database.MySQL.createTable(MySQL.java:104)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   power.managers.DatabaseManager.createTables(DatabaseManager.java:81)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   power.managers.DatabaseManager.startDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:40)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   power.managers.DatabaseManager.(DatabaseManager.java:30)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   power.logic.ClanBattles.onEnable(ClanBattles.java:44) [23:51:36 WARN]:
>   at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:321)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:340)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:405)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:357)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:317)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:741)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:535)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:25)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:641)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1162)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:997)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:45)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:1)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown
>   Source) [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:44) [23:51:36
>   WARN]:        at
>   net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.B(MinecraftServer.java:715)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:374)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:654)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at
>   net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:557)
>   [23:51:36 WARN]:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Could you provide the proper stacktrace to check the whole error message from MySQL?

Comment: its an error from a minecraft console, that is all the stacktrace, in fact the same error is displayed two times, the first creating regions table the second creating the locations table. The query seem to be ok, but probably theres something im missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are creating the foreign keys in reverse direction which is not correct.

Since your `map` table has `regionId` then you should create a `FOREIGN KEY` in the map table for it, not in the `region` itself. So change it in the script for creating the `map` table this way:

```
FOREIGN KEY (regionId) REFERENCES regions(id)
```

The same applies for `maxLocationId` column of `region` table. The foreign key should be defined in the `region` table not in the `locations` itself.

Any foreign key should reference a `PRIMARY KEY` in the referencing table, and if it doesn't mysql would not create it.

Also you should keep a dependency order in creating tables and defining their PRIMARY KEYs, and then creating any referencing FOREIGN KEYs between them.

For example you should first create the `region` table and define its PRIMARY KEY. After that you should create your `map` table which has a reference to `region` and now you can define the foreign key in `map` table which references the `id` (or generally the PRIMARY KEY) of `region` table on its `regionId` column.

Please see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) reference for the concept and syntax of creating foreign keys.

Comment: well i make a ERR diagram to test the relation between the tables, when i delete one row of he maps table i want to delete the region and the locations related to the map. i will try to do in the opposite order and check if it works thanks by the way.

Comment: I change the order of the relation, but when i try to delete a map the region and the 3 locations related to that map are still there, but if i delete the location id 1 and a map exists with referenceId = 1 that map will be deleted too. the same happends if i delete a location with id = 2 and one region have a minLocationId = 2 or maxLocationId = 2

Comment: Did your problem about creating foreign keys resolved or not?

Comment: Im still not capable to delete a map and his rows related.

Comment: When you want to delete a `map` and it's related `location` rows from `location` table you should maintain a `one-to-many` relation from `map` table to `location` table. This means that you should have a foreign-key named (for example) `map_id` in the `location` table which means many locations records in `location` table are belong to one record in `map` table (one map record is the parent of many location records). Using this and setting the correct properties on the foreign key for `ON DELETE` to `CASCADE` you will be able to delete on map record and then location records will be deleted.

Comment: thanks, then i must have a map_id and a region_id in locations table because both tables contains objects from locations table.

Comment: Thats right. You should have map_id and region_id in your locations table since both are parent entities for locations. In other word a map contains many locations and a region contains many locations too.

Answer (score 0):

why you have FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES maps (regionId) inside your region table? it should be the other way isn't it (region table is the master table and its id referenced by table maps)?

so it should be like this inside create table maps DDL

```
FOREIGN KEY (regionId) REFERENCES region (id)
ON DELETE CASCADE 
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

same thing with FK inside location table, i think should be the other way around

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create more than one primary key in one table
Like you did in Maps table

```
"CREATE TABLE maps (" 
                + "name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,"
                + "mapType VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,"
                + "world VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,"
                + "referenceId INT(32) NOT NULL,"
                + "regionId INT(32) NOT NULL,"
                + "testmode BIT(1) NOT NULL,"
                + "edition BIT(1) NOT NULL,"
                + "finished BIT(1) NOT NULL,"
                + "PRIMARY KEY (name, referenceId, regionId))"
                + "ENGINE = InnoDB "
                + "DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;";
```

and to create foreign key constraint, you have to give reference of primary key of that table, with which you want to bind your current table

have a look
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int NOT NULL,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set a unique name of all constraints.
Name of constraints must unique in the whole database.